# Avoid Cascade workflow execution

Tags: workflow, case

I´ve following workflow rules:

**W1:**
on Case Comment object ----action: update field on case.

**W2:**
on case object----action: change case status

Field update on case of W1 is firing W2, I would like to avoid this cascade execution.

Do you know how?

Comment: You can't prevent W2 from being *evaluated* when W1 fires. The Case record is being edited, and this will cause the workflow rules to be evaluated. So you'll need to adjust your criteria. Can you update your question to include the criteria for both rules, and which evaluation option each has?

Answer (score 0):

as Thomas said in his answer it will automatically reevaluate the rules.

What you can do is add a flag on the record to stop workflow rules.

1. Have your first workflow set it to true
2. Have your second workflow check for a value to be false in order to fire
3. Create a third workflow that if the flag is true, set it to false

**Notes on 3 - If a workflow rule is set to reevaluate workflow rules take this into account in your workflow rule that looks at the flag
- Since the workflow to set it to false only evaluates to true after the first workflow it will not cause workflows to be evaluated again when it is set to false.

Or - if you can work your workflows to evaluate properly based on themselves in isolation there will be no need for this. As an example: